# How to redirect login to a home page whose template is inside app not at project level :python django

Tags: python-3.x, django

Normally using inbuilt login system in django the login page is set inside the projects setting.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "home"
```

The above code works if the template is at a project level directory i.e
'django_project/templates'. What if the templates are inside app i.e 'django_project/app_name/templates' ?

Answer (score 0):

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL can point to a url or a path name from urlpatterns.

e.g

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'polls_app_name:index_name`

or

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'polls_url/index_path`
(which is less "django style")
```

if you setup the apps urls.py similar like below with a name even with an app_name (= namespace)

```
app_name = "polls_app_name"
urlpatterns = [
    path("index_path", views.IndexView.as_view(), name="index_name"),
    path("<int:pk>/", views.DetailView.as_view(), name="detail"),
    ...,
]
```

include polls app url in main app urls like

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("polls_url/", include("polls.urls")),
    
    # ... 
]
```

note: only included urls.py can have an app_name for name spacing. Not the main urls.py

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns